# Hibernate join table restrictions

Tags: java, hibernate

I have the following tables:

[ table : column1, column2 ]

A : id, name

B : id, name

AB : idA, idB

AB is a join table.

Then I have this method on hibernate class B

```
@OneToMany( fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
@JoinTable( name = "AB", 
            joinColumns = @JoinColumn( name = "idB"),
            inverseJoinColumns = @JoinColumn( name = "idA") )
public List<A> getAs(){
    //return the list of matching stuff
}
```

This works perfectly fine.

Now I want to do this sql query in hibernate:

```
select * from B inner join AB on B.id = AB.idB where AB.idA = 1234
```

Essentially, 'list me all B's that reference A with id 1234'

I could do straight sql, but that would defeat the purpose of getAs()

Is it possible to construct a Criterion/Restriction clause to achieve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Relationship between `A` and `B` is not one-to-many in this case, but rather many-to-many. You should map it as such:

```
@ManyToMany
@JoinTable(name = "AB", 
            joinColumns = @JoinColumn( name = "idB"),
            inverseJoinColumns = @JoinColumn( name = "idA") )
public List<A> getAs(){
    //return the list of matching stuff
}
```

Note that eagerly fetching a collection is not a good idea in most cases, hence `fetch = FetchType.EAGER` removed above. You can now do the same on `A` side to make relationship bidirectional:

```
@ManyToMany(mappedBy='As')
public List<B> getBs(){
    //return the list of matching stuff
}
```

Now getting all `B`s for given `A` is just a matter of calling `getBs()` on that `A` instance. You can create criteria / write HQL to do that as well - from either side.

Comment: makes sense.  btw, if I left fetch = FetchType.EAGER, what would happen?

Comment: @Ken Eager fetch means Hibernate would attempt to retrieve all associated `A`s when you try to get your `B`. If `A` were to have its collection of `B`s mapped with eager fetch as well, the same would apply, and so on. Having all fetches set to eager can easily lead to you retrieving the entire database every time you get a single entity.

Comment: Collection attributes are treated as `LAZY` by default which is dictated by the JPA specification.

Comment: @ChssPly76 why did you assume that this must be `ManyToMany` relationship?

Comment: @Piotr - Ken mapped it as one-to-many on `B` and he was asking how to get multiple `B`s for a given `A`. That's many-to-many.